# prevent scrolling when I use url fragment

Tags: angular

I have angular 5 where I need to implement a new function,

I have a search page where everything is working fine, I have some buttons to choose between the location, date and other filter, here we add a fragment to the url when the user presses on of the filters.

My problem is I want to implement a dropdown button for another view mode, just for locations,
I used the code in the filter code, and it works, but the page is gets focused when I choose a location (I have cookie so, any new load page goes to the new page I implement (which is in the end of the page)).

I think I know why, but I do not know how to do it in the right way.

so, I use the fragment and I search in the store and send the location value to it to get the data I want, but that also change the url (#/location:london) , and it scrolls the page to the area where I use this appModule,
please anyone has any explanation?

```
 <fieldset>
<div class="row location-dropdown" >  
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="location-selector" i18n="@@lnkShowEventsFor.label">Show events for: </label>
  <select tabindex="-1" [autofocus]="false"  class="col-sm-2 form-control-static" [ngModel]="selectedLocation"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" name="location-selector" (ngModelChange)="onChangeObj($event)" >
     <option [ngValue]="null" i18n="@@lnkAllLocation.label">All locations</option>
     <option [ngValue]="value"  *ngFor="let value of values|slice:0:end" >{{value}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="isShowMore()">
    <div class="arena-facet-show-all">
      <a class="arena-show-all" href="javascript:" (click)="showMore()" title="Show all" i18n="@@lnkShowAllLocations.label" i18n-title="@@lnkShowAllLocations.title">
        Show all
      </a>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

```
export class LocationDropdownSelectorComponent  extends ToggleListComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedLocation: any = null;
  cookieSavedDays: number ;

 constructor( private calendarEventListConfig: CalendarEventListConfig, private store$: 
 Store<fromRoot.State>) {
super();
}

ngOnInit() {
this.cookieSavedDays = this.calendarEventListConfig.getCookieSavedDays();
this.selectedLocation = Cookie.load('SELECTED_LOCATION_VALUE');
this.store$.dispatch(new SearchActions.Search({query: {'locations': this.selectedLocation}}));
 }

 onChangeObj(e: string) {
   const isAllLocation = !this.values.find(element => element === e);
   if (isAllLocation) {
    this.store$.dispatch(new SearchActions.Search({query: {'locations': []}}));
   Cookie.remove('SELECTED_LOCATION_VALUE', '/');
   } else {
   this.store$.dispatch(new SearchActions.Search({query: {'locations': [e]}}));
   Cookie.save( 'SELECTED_LOCATION_VALUE', e, this.cookieSavedDays, '/');
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase this helps anyone else, my page was scrolling to the html element that had the ID tag of the fragment in the url before the page was fully loaded and removing `anchorScrolling: 'enabled'` from the app-routing.module.ts within fixed the issue.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      //anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```